# Celery not consuming all messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Am consuming messages from rabbitmq but the consumer seems to accept then deny accept then deny (in the same format) accept one then deny the next message

```
[MainProcess] Received message: RT @Iamsidneyy: Kenya in scientific terms 

[WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: 'The greatest enemy of knowledge is not ignorance, it is the illusion of knowledge.\n\n—Stephen Hawking' (133b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None5', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': 'twitterstatus', 'routing_key': 'twitterstatus'} headers={}}


[MainProcess] Received message: RT @fideloper: Coming together!

[WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: 'Lol all of mine are memes :’)' (60b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None5', 'delivery_tag': 2, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': 'twitterstatus', 'routing_key': 'twitterstatus'} headers={}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using

```
celery worker -A app -Q twitterstatus -l info
```

seems like using queue option made it that way now using

```
celery worker -A app -l info
```

works fine